# Approximating volume of a multivariable function from a contour plot using the midpoint rule

Tags: calculus

I'm taking an online Calc III class, but the professor is not particularly helpful. I keep getting the homework question marked wrong by the software we use. Am I doing something wrong?

The question displays a contour map for a function $f$ on the square $R = [0,6] \times [0,6]$.
[image]

For part (a) it asks us to use the Midpoint Rule with $m=n=2$ to estimate the value of $\iint_R f(x,y)~dA$. Here is my work:

$$
\begin{align*}
\iint_R f(x,y)~dA &\approx \sum_{j=1}^2 \sum_{i=1}^2 f(\bar{x}_i, \bar{y}_j) \Delta A \\[1em] 
&= \Delta A \big(f(1.5, 1.5) + f(4.5, 1.5) + f(1.5, 4.5) + f(4.5, 4.5)\big) \\[1em]
&= 9(57+44+4+47) \\[1em]
&= 1368
\end{align*}
$$
Part (b) then asks us to estimate the average value of $f$:

$$
\begin{align*}
f_{ave} = \frac{1}{A}\iint_R f(x,y) \Delta A \approx \frac{1368}{36} = 38
\end{align*}
$$

I calculated $\Delta A = \dfrac{A}{m\times n} = \dfrac{6^2}{4} = 9$.

Is this correct?